# How to queue ajax calls or make sure every ajax call is executed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have built a chat application.The user type messages and press enter to send the message.When user types message and press enter one after another in mater of a second (I mean sends multiple messages in a second), then some messages are not sent to the server. I have used jquery ajax to post messages.
How can I make sure that all messages are sent.

Comment: put that code here so we can suggest something

Comment: what about `async= true` ???

Comment: I set async= true and async=false, but still not working

Comment: Show us some code so we can try and get an idea of what might be wrong.